# how to get values of Form1.cs into another .cs file

Tags: c#

this is code in `Form1.cs`. I want to get values of f_name, L_name etc in next dbfun.cs.

```
private void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string f_name = first_name.Text;
    string L_name = last_name.Text;
    string user_email = email.Text;
    string pass = password.Text;
    string depart = department.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string gender = "";
    if (male.Checked)
    {
        gender = "Male";
    }
    else if (female.Checked)
    {
        gender = "Female";
    }
    String agree = accept.Text;
}
```

Comment: Is `dbfun` a class that you have an instance of somewhere? is it static? what have you tried/researched?

Comment: i made dbfun.cs class separately and want to access values of f_name,L_name etc which are defined in Form1.cs,

Comment: but there is error in f_name,L_name etc ,when i put them in dbfun.cs.

Comment: Great, where? how? Your question is unclear, see my first comment

Comment: class dbfun
    {
        public void insert()
        {   
            string f_name = first_name.Text;
            string L_name = last_name.Text;
            string user_email = email.Text;
            string pass = password.Text;
            string depart = department.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string gender = "";
            if (male.Checked)
            {
                gender = "Male";
            }
            else if (female.Checked)
            {
                gender = "Female";
            }
            String agree = accept.Text;

Comment: there is "public void insert()" where i put first_name.Text,last_name.Text.etc

Comment: Please could you edit your question to include more information about what you're doing, and what the _exact_ error is.

Comment: Just start using MVVM pattern and messengers -_-

Answer (score 0):

There nothing to do. Just create an object instance on Form2 with required number of Parameters for passing the values to Form2

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(textBox1.Text);            
        f2.Show();
    }


    public Form2(string value)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox2.Text = value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace ValuesPassingFromformtoform
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }


            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string f_name = first_name.Text;
                string L_name = last_name.Text;
                string user_email = email.Text;
                string pass = password.Text;
                string depart = department.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string gender = "";


                Form2 f2 = new Form2(f_name,L_name,user_email,pass,depart);            
                f2.Show();
            }
        }
    }

and Form2.cs is

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ValuesPassingFromformtoform
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2(string f_name, string L_name, string user_email, string pass, string depart)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox2.Text = f_name;

        }

    }
}
```